# IObservable doesnt Contain the defintion, but actualy there is the definition in there

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, akavache

I Try to load cached data via Akavache, but i dont know why i cant get it right. i try to get FullName and Email that i already cached after login , so i getobject in my "CachedUser" model but dont know why its says there is no definition for FullName and Email in there. 
Here is my CachedUser Model

```
namespace KGVC.Models
{
    public class CachedUsers
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is the code to getobject in Akavache that i try to implement

```
   public void GetDataCache(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var loaded =  BlobCache.LocalMachine.GetObject<CachedUsers>("usercached");

            txtemail.Text = loaded.FullName;
            txtfullname.Text = loaded.FullName.ToString();
        }
```

and here is the cache user code

```
 public  void CacheUser(AuthenticationResult ar)
        {
            JObject user = ParseIdToken(ar.IdToken);
            var cache = new CachedUsers
            {
                FullName = user["name"]?.ToString(),
                Email = user["emails"]?.ToString()

            };
             BlobCache.LocalMachine.InsertObject("usercached", cache);

        }
```

and here is the full error message that i get

```
'IObservable<CachedUsers>' does not contain a definition for 'FullName' and no extension method 'FullName' accepting a first argument of type 'IObservable<CachedUsers>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

what is the problem in here , because i think there is nothing wrong in my code. can you figure this out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to await it

```
 public async void GetDataCache(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var loaded = await BlobCache.LocalMachine.GetObject<CachedUsers>("usercached");

    txtemail.Text = loaded.FullName;
    txtfullname.Text = loaded.FullName.ToString();
 }
```

or subscribe to the `IObservable`:

```
 public async void GetDataCache(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var loaded = await BlobCache.LocalMachine.GetObject<CachedUsers>("usercached").Subscribe(user => {
        // TODO might need to wrap this in a Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread
        txtemail.Text = user.FullName;
        txtfullname.Text = user.FullName.ToString();
    });
 }
```

Look into the concepts of async/await and the `IObservable` object to get a better understanding of the concepts and what the problem is in this specific case.

Comment: thanks bro its work with the Subscribe, but there is something that make me wonder i cant use await for it and its said IObservable doesnt contain the definition for get Awaiter. but in the end my code is work, I'm just curious here ahahhaha

Comment: Ah I don't have actual code right now to check it out for you. From memory I remembered something like this and I thought you could do one of both. So probably an overload of that method. But maybe it got removed in recent versions. Glad it helped!

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang including a using statement for `System.Reactive.Linq` is what gives you the ability to await an observable